Long time for queuing to call API
I am facing issue when add extra headers to the request like 'API-Key': 'xxxxxxxxx' I noticed the request take longer time.
please see the two screenshots from chrome when perform the same request without that extra key in the header.
With the extra header key

without the extra header key

how I can kill that extra waiting time ?


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <title>API Calls</title>
    <script>
        async function fetchApi(url, headers) {
            const response = await fetch(url, {
                method: 'GET',
                headers: headers
            });
            const data = await response.json();
            return data;
        }

        async function callApis() {
            const apiCalls = [
               
                {
                    name: 'Random User',
                    url: 'https://randomuser.me/api/',
                    headers: {
                        'accept': 'application/json',
                        'API-Key': 'xxxxxxxxx'
                    }
                },
                
            ];

            const resultsContainer = document.getElementById('results');
            resultsContainer.innerHTML = '';

            for (const api of apiCalls) {
                const startTime = performance.now(); // Start timing
                const data = await fetchApi(api.url, api.headers);
                const endTime = performance.now(); // End timing
                const duration = endTime - startTime; // Calculate duration
                resultsContainer.innerHTML += `<h3>${api.name}</h3><pre>${JSON.stringify(data, null, 2)}</pre><p>Duration: ${duration.toFixed(2)} ms</p>`;
            }
        }

        // Call the APIs when the window loads
        window.onload = callApis;
    </script>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>API Calls Results</h1>
    <div id="results"></div>
</body>
</html>




Assuming this difference is consistent: It seems the extra 50 ms is taken up by the server that responds to your API request. So you need the code, answering the API request, to get to the bottom of this. The documentation of https://randomuser.me says nothing about extra headers, as far as I can see. You can check the source code

Thanks @KIKOSoftware. this is just example. Am taking in general not related to exact randomuser

A single header, like this, would only be a small part of an API request, so there's no clear reason why it would add 50 ms to the request. I can invent several: 1. The API needs to do extra processing when it receives such an header. 2. Something in your browser (a plugin?) helps to protect your privacy and scans for outgoing headers like this, and checks them for violations. 3. You think such a request takes longer, but it doesn't really. Note that we cannot verify your assertion.

Maybe the server looks up your api key in a database, and that takes 50ms

In public APIs, the API key is not mandatory, but in private APIs, it is required for authentication and access. The delay when using the API key is likely due to server-side processing, like authentication or security checks. You can make parallel requests to reduce the overall time, and if the key isn’t mandatory, consider removing it to improve response speed

Try to avoid speculations like: "is likely due to", in an answer. Use a comment instead.

Amisha is not correct. by definition Queueing. The browser queues requests before the connection starts to server
